# Canbus - slcan and mPCIe CAN module from Apacer (EFC-D10)

Tags: linux

We are trying to make Canbus work on an industrial PC with an EFC-D10 module from Apacer and CP2105 Dual USB to UART bridge controller. We are using Linux kernel 4.19.129 which contains a driver for CP2105. From dmesg:

```
[    2.347510] usb 1-3: Product: CP2105 Dual USB to UART Bridge Controller
[    2.349828] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[    2.351386] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 00A1240E
[...]
[    5.262243] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[    5.263581] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[    5.271657] cp210x 1-3:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[    5.302067] usb 1-3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    5.303403] cp210x 1-3:1.1: cp210x converter detected
[    5.307509] usb 1-3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

So far everything is good. Then a direct invocation of slcand seems to work:

```
slcand -o -c -f -s4 /dev/ttyUSB0 can0
ip link set can0 up
```

From journalctl:

```
slcand[1266]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyUSB0
slcand[1267]: attached TTY /dev/ttyUSB0 to netdevice slcan0
kernel: can0: renamed from slcan0
slcand[1267]: netdevice slcan0 renamed to can0
systemd-networkd[140]: can0: Link UP
systemd-networkd[140]: can0: Gained carrier
```

And we can see local traffic sent with cansend, using candump, but we don't see any external traffic. We have tried to set serial baud rate (using -S option) and everything else we can control from slcand, but it makes no difference. And we have tested with a normal USB to Can adapter, starting slcan with the same command, and it works. And we have read the user manual.

This might of course be a hardware problem, but I have read that there is different support for  the SLCAN protocol in different cards. Could it be that slcand doesn't support this card?

So the real questions is, does anyone have any experience with the EFC-D10 module from Apacer on Linux? (We have contacted the producer without getting any feedback.)